# ImageView shows same picture on both ImageView clicked by one

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I have two `ImageView` one `img1` and second is img2. I wanna capture an image from camera to click on both `ImageView` and show on it. But here is problem that I am clicking image from click on `img1` and same image showing on both `ImageView`. If I click on `img1` and click image from there then `img2` also showing same picture without click on there if I am clicking on `img2` then click an image from there then that picture showing on `img1` also.
I wanna to show differ images which is clicked by camera on both differ `ImageView`.

```
img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, requestcode);
        }
    });

    img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, requestcode);
        }
    });


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (this.requestcode  == requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        img2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } 
}
```

Comment: set a flag on button click. check the flag onActivityResult and set the image based on the flag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use different `Request codes` for both `ImageView` using `switch` case for that so problem will not occur. Currently you are using same `Request` code for both `Image View`.

Like

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    switch(requestCode){
        case 0: // Do your stuff here...
            img1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        break;
        case 1: // Do your other stuff here...
            img2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        break;

    }
}
```

Inside `onClickListener`.

```
img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });

    img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.chatting.gourav.maintenance/com.chatting.gourav.maintenance.Detail_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference

Comment: @gouravmanuja Try updated *onActivityResult* method now it will work. Changed *public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)* to *public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)*.

Comment: it run successfully man but when i captured both image then i again click on some imageview then i saw again camera and got an option to capture again at that time when i click on another side of screen this error occurred.